# Quartz Installer refuses to use a dual mount sink - only undermount?

Tags: sink, kitchen-counters, countertops, contractors

The company installing my quartz countertops says that the sink I provided, a dual mount ( https://www.elkay.com/products/hddsb33229tr3.html ) is not usable and that I must provide a true undermount. I have tried researching this extensively and can't find any information about this online.

Is this really a thing? I can't for the life of me understand why they would say the dual mount is not usable.

Comment: I agree with them and I would worry about hiring someone else.   That person that agrees to install it may also be the person that ruins your expensive countertop.

Comment: And to that point as a homeowner - you should never let anyone but the company you bought the stone from install your countertop or cut it or make holes to install the sink.   Never ever.   If the company quotes you $200 for a 20 min job, pay them and factor that into the cost.   Or better think ahead and only agree to use them for installing the sink.   Honestly most of the good quality countertop companies near me always install sink for free and would highly question anyone else doing it.   Not saying you haven't done this, just saying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The sink you linked to is a nice sink.   I would certainly use it as a drop-in.
2. I get the installers question this as an undermount.   Undermounts usually do not have faucet holes built into them and I can see how this could add complexity and possible issues.   To add... this job goes from... mark sink (measure of course) and drill to a very complex math/aligning task.   There is no lip on the front that says the edge goes here - meaning you could drill holes and they may be off by 1/8" too far or too close to the sink, either making the install a fail (gap) or at best making the sink not centered.
   Also think about this.   You get it installed, you drill the holes and you think everything looks great.   You install faucet and you don't notice the stem is putting pressure on one of the holes in a certain direction... done.   Then two weeks later you are washing dishes and sink starts pulling out (I can tell you how to install undermounts 100% fool-proof that never come out)... well its because those damn holes are meant for a drop in - actually the whole top part.
3. So undermounting would be pretty easy if this were laminate (wood based) countertop.   I would simply glue it in, support it... and the next day drill a pilot from the bottom and go from there.   Still harder than it should be but with wood based countertop, nothing is going to crack or have major issues.

**Verdict - Not often I do this... but I am siding with your installers here.**   You want something installed that is half-baked for the application then you install it.   If you want undermount, then get an undermount sink.   Yes this may have the ability to be an undermount but that is not what it was made for.   It is just a silly selling point to get people to buy it.   My installers would probably install it but charge me an extra $100 and that's only because they do a lot of work for me.

Comment: This is pretty dead on. installer said they used to install these but they broke too many sinks drilling the faucet hole and hitting the sink. what i dont really understand is why not mount the undermount from the top (with the quartz flipped upside down), then its easy to drill the faucet hole, then flip back around. But maybe that's too difficult due to weight to easily do, not sure. In any case, they're going to install it for me and let me drill the hole. I'll be careful to make sure im in the right place. long as i dont hit the sink should be fine, my faucet has trim to hide imperfections

Comment: @user67081 I'm not following: they are going to install the sink then hand you the drill? Or hand you the drill, let you drill, and then install while aligning the hole? Seems all they did was shift liability. IMO this doesn't address DMoore's valid concerns.

Comment: @P2000 - I agree.   He shouldn't install it.   There is nothing ground breaking about that sink... its nice but I can find a like undermount in 10 mins.       I have done a lot of kitchens.   Refacing, cabinets, counters, everything...   I never drill my holes in granite/quartz/stone unless I HAVE TO.   So the only times is when I have repurposed or if I am drilling an extra hole way after an install.   I have the right equipment and practice but it risk vs reward.   Why would I pay 1.5k-3k for countertops and ruin it for something so small.   Installer ruins it they replace it.

Comment: @P2000 - I also think your suggestions have a myriad of flaws and pitfalls.   The slight back-kick on drilling could cause a crack...   Taking an angle grinder to that sink... wow no not unless you are a metal fabricator.   At best when cutting it out you have a lip that isn't flat.   It doesn't make sense to take something brand new and bastardize it when you can easily easily buy something that would work.   The OP here is just overthinking this.

Comment: I understand the concerns but this is in a remote house and they brought up this sink issue last minute and would cause an extra 2 months of delay if they couldn't template it yesterday. I couldn't swap sinks in a day (they require it on site). I'm not too concerned about drilling the hole myself (already have the right size diamond hole saw from my bath remodel). I'll post back with an update (regardless of if I'm successful or manage to screw it up.)

Comment: Just don't cut it with the sink attached.   Those hole saws will kick wherever if they hit something like that and with some force.

Answer (score 3):

I have used drop-in sinks for under mounting. I have even cut double drop-in sinks and under-mounted them as a single sink, in a *granite* counter top.

The important aspect is the flatness of the rim of the sink, and the gap between the top of the sink and the top of rim, because this is what you'll have to fill with silcone. Absence of mounting brackets is not an issue.

You need to provide sufficient support with all-round and/or brackets *under* the sink. If they don't do it for you, you could tell them to cut the opening and you'll install it yourself.

If the installer objects to drilling faucet holes at the precise locations provided by the sink, you can modify that sink: cut off the lip around the holes with an angle grinder and give them more tolerance.

Be careful not to bend the sink. And you need clearance from the basin. I've done it; it takes some patience. Sand it smooth to avoid injury, but it doesn't have to be pretty as it goes under the counter.

However, it should be within their skillset to drill those holes exactly as required.

If their argument is that the top of the sink is not flat enough, well, that makes little sense because it is a dual mount sink and it is designed flat enough to serve as an undermount.

Comment: +1. If Elkay calls it an undermount, then it's an undermount. The installer might have a problem with the sub-top (or absence thereof) -- as noted, have a good conversation with them. Maybe they aren't the installer for you...

Comment: I talked to the installer customer service agent - they claimed something about the flatness of the top and the cutting of holes for the faucet was difficult so they dont do them? I still dont quite understand, i guess maybe true undermount doesnt have a hole for the faucet so theres no need to carefully line up the drill? but thats the hole point of using the sink manufacturers template to cut it... the actual installer is coming today to template and im going to figure out what really is the issue.

Comment: @user67081 If you are savvy you can cut off the lip around the holes with a angle grinder and give them more tolerance. Be careful not to bend the sink.And you need clearance from the basin. I've done it, takes some patience. Sand it smooth to avoid injury but it doesn't have to be pretty as it goes under the counter. WRT the top, it's flat enough as a dual mount, so that's just an excuse on their behalf. Good luck!